# Lowercase field name in Logstash for Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash command that I'm piping a file to that will write to Elasticsearch.  I want to use one field to select the index I will write to (`appName`).  However the data in this field is not all lowercase so I need to do that when selecting the index but I don't want the data in the document itself to be modified.

I have an attempt below where I first copy the original field (`appName`) to a new one (`appNameIndex`), lowercase the new field, remove it from the upload and then use it pick the index.

```
input {
      stdin { type => stdin }
}
filter {
  csv {
     separator => " "
     columns => ["appName", "field1", "field2", ...]
     convert => {
         ...
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    copy => ["appName", "appNameIndex"]
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    lowercase => ["appNameIndex"]
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [
      "appNameIndex", // if I remove this it works
       ...
    ]
  }
}

output {
   amazon_es {
     hosts =>
         ["my-es-cluster.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
     index => "%{appNameIndex}"
     region => "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

However I am getting errors that say

```
Invalid index name [%{appIndexName}]
```

Clearly it's not grabbing my mutation.  Is it because the remove section takes it out entirely?  I was hoping that just removed it from the document upload.  Am I going about this incorrectly?

**UPDATE** I tried taking out the remove index name part and it does in fact work, so that helps identify the source of the error.  Now the question becomes how do I get around it.  With that part of the config removed I essentially have two fields with the same data, one lowercased and one not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a `@metadata` field that is a special field which will never be included in the output https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#metadata.

```
input {
  stdin { type => stdin }
}
filter {
   csv {
      separator => " "
      columns => ["appName", "field1", "field2", ...]
      convert => {
      ...
   }
}
filter {
   mutate {
      copy => ["appName", "[@metadata][appNameIndex]"]
   }
}
filter {
   mutate {
      lowercase => ["[@metadata][appNameIndex]"]
   }
}
output {
   amazon_es {
      hosts => ["my-es-cluster.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
      index => "%{[@metadata][appNameIndex]}"
      region => "us-east-1"
   }
}
```